# Weak form of cahn hilliard equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method, variational-analysis

I am trying to write the weak formulation of Cahn-hilliard equation as under.

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \nabla .\{\phi(1-\phi) [\phi(1-\phi)\nabla \mu - \nabla (A(\phi)q)]\}$

$\frac{\partial q}{\partial t} = - \frac{q}{T(\phi)} -A(\phi)\nabla . [[\phi(1-\phi)\nabla \mu - \nabla (A(\phi)q)]]$

For the first equation, if w is the test function then,

$(\phi_t,w)+(\phi^2(1-\phi)^2\nabla \mu, \nabla w)-(\phi(1-\phi)\nabla A(\phi)q,\nabla w)=([\phi(1-\phi)\nabla \mu - \nabla (A(\phi)q)],w)_{boundary}$

Kindly guide me, where I am committing mistake

Comment: You need to provide some boundary and initial conditions.